Looking for an old children’s book that has a monster eating children
I’m in my 30s and checked out this really old (old back then) book all the time. It was something about a monster who ate kids, I think, and the monster always said “yada yada yada psu psu psu” or something. I remember something about revenge of the ____ - it started with a v. Something like vengananny.

You can find some matching titles at https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=revenge+of+the&type=Fiction+Titles but I don't see any with your word.
